# How to access methods from main regarding an array

Tags: java, arrays, instance

```
public class Prog19_01 {

      int [] list;
      int size;

    public void bubbleSort()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length - i - 1; j ++)
                if (list [j] > list [j+1] )
                {
                    // awap list {j} and list {j+1}
                    int temp = list [j];
                    list[j] = list [j+1];
                    list [j+1] = temp;
                }
    }

    public void fillArray()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            list [i] = (int)(Math.random()*100); 
        }
    }

    public void printArray()
    {
         for ( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
         {
             System.out.println( list[i]);
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

       // I want to be able to do something like list.fillArray(); and 
       // list.printArray() but it doesnt work it reads
    }
}
```

Someone said to do
Prog19_01 array = new Prog19_01();
to be able to access the methods which it works. can someone explain me why this code?

now when i do this
array.fillArray();

it gives me
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at prog19_01.Prog19_01.fillArray(Prog19_01.java:30)
    at prog19_01.Prog19_01.main(Prog19_01.java:46)
C:\Users\casti\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

which points to line on fillArray
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)

and same error when i do 
array.printArray();

which points to line on printArray
 for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiate a class? How to call an instance method? What is your question?

Comment: Create a `Prog19_01 o = new Prog19_01()`.  Then you can call those functions on `o`.

Comment: Your code compiles fine in Eclipse and Javac. This is a problem with Netbeans, see duplicate. It should be fixed in the newest version of Netbeans: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199293

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that worked on accessing the methods, i updated my question, why is this code necessary? and see the errors it gives me now